# ClientError when calling CreateFlowDefinition operation in 'Intelligent Document Processing with AWS AI Services'

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker, amazon-textract

Within the notebook Amazon Augmented AI (A2I) and Textract Analyze Document, the error occurs after the following script being ran

```
uniqueId = str(uuid.uuid4())
flowDefinitionName = f'fd-textract-{uniqueId}'

flowDefinitionArn = create_flow_definition(flowDefinitionName)
```

The following error returns:

> ClientError: An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the CreateFlowDefinition operation: 1 validation error detected: Value 'arn:aws:sagemaker:ap-southeast-1:xxxxxxxxxxxx:flow-definition/a2idemotextract' at 'humanLoopConfig.workteamArn' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy regular expression pattern: arn:aws[a-z-]:sagemaker:[a-z0-9-]:[0-9]{12}:workteam/.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve the problem, double check to make sure you are using the right ARN in WORKTEAM_ARN to solve the error received.